# Using Census Geocoder to get latitude and longitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, geocoding

I have never used Python before or made a call to an API so I am a little lost. I need to send an address to
https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.html#_Toc143583220
and get back the latitude and longitude.
All of the help I could find was about addressbatch which I don't need.

The address I am using is a random one given on the command line :)

Here's what I have (which is very much not working) How do I get the api to return the lat and long?

```
def main():
    #reading URL input
    urlIn = sys.argv[1]

    IP = socket.gethostbyname(urlIn)

    res = subprocess.getstatusoutput("whois " + IP)
    ressplit = res[1].split("\n")
    #parsing address from result
    for i in ressplit:
        if i.startswith("Address: "):
            a = i[10:]
        if i.startswith("City: "):
            c = i[6:]
        if i.startswith("StateProv: "):
            s = i[11:]
        if i.startswith("PostalCode: "):
            p = i[12:]
            break

    #combining to make address
    address = a.strip() + ", " + c.strip() + ", " + s.strip() + " " + p.strip()
    print(address)

    #base API string for geocoding.gov
    geo_s = "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/address?"
    location = address
    PARAMS = {'address':location}

    response = requests.get(url = geo_s, params = PARAMS)
    data = response.json()
    #convert it to json
    geojs = json.loads(response.text)
    latitude = data['x']
    longitude = data ['y']
```

and what it looks like from the terminal:

```
cscd330lab2 % ./lab2.py "youtube.com"
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emilyherbert/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emilyherbert/Desktop/cscd330lab2/./lab2.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/emilyherbert/Desktop/cscd330lab2/./lab2.py", line 40, in main
    data = response.json()
  File "/Users/emilyherbert/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: well it looks like to `response` is not `json` - debug or print it out to examine.  Also when I try to do `https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/address?1600%20Amphitheatre%20Parkway,%20Mountain%20View,%20CA%2094043` it does not seem to work either

Comment: You need to focus your question down to a specific issue, saying it doesn't work is not a question.  What specifically doesn't work?  From the data it seems, you are generating a valid address as text.  If you pass this address to the geocoder using the api directly, do you get the response you desire?  What other debug steps have you taken?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips.